# Injecting objects to class instance

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I was wondering if the following is possible in python 2.7 or 3.x:

```
Class A:
    def inject(self, **args):
        ... do something ...

    def print(self):
        print(self.x)

x = np.ones(10)
a = A()
a.inject(x)
a.print()
```

Note that I want `inject` to be very general and be able to add any object to the class instance.

What are your thoughts? Is this how I imagined possible?

### Edit:

I also would like to inject many variables to the additional injected:

```
y = np.ones(10)
z = np.ones(10)
a.inject(y, z)
```

Comment: Why do you need `inject`? You can just add an attribute to a class instance, eg `a.x = x`.

Comment: I know, but I would also like to use something like ```a.inject(x, y)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you should use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class A:
    def inject(self, name, value):
        setattr(self, name, value)

    def print(self):
        print(self.x)

x = [1, 1]
a = A()
a.inject('x', x)
a.print()
>> [1, 1]
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I use now. But I thought maybe I can save the redundant step of the naming ```a.inject('x', x)``` as the variable ```x``` itself already contains the name ```'x'```

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan No, you can't. The list `[1, 1]` has no idea whatsoever that there is a reference to it that happens to be called `x`.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan:  variable don't contain their own names.  The objects they are referring to might have names of their own, but variables do not.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also see, [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is to use `setattr(a, "x", x)`.

But if you want to use this call in `inject(self, name, value)` function, then it might be useful to add check which would prevent overwriting an existing attribute - You might want to use `if hasattr(self, name): raise AttributeError('attribute already exists')` or something like that. Without this check you might be quite surprised someday what is happenning with your objects after you have accidentally overwritten attributes. Just imagine 'accidental' `a.inject("inject", x)` ;)

But looking at your code, you are trying to use something like 'Python-with-classes' and it looks too 'java-ish'. In Python, you do not need to define `inject()` and `print()` in your class. You can simply write:

```
a = object()
x = 5
setattr(a, "x", x)
print(a.x)  # btw. how does your implementation `a.print()` in the question knows that attribute `x` exists?
```

I you want to prevent overwriting existing attributes (i.e. allow only the first injections) and still be pythonic, define your class like this:

```
class A(object):  # note the 'object' here, it is the 'new style' class
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            raise AttributeError("attribute '{}' already exists".format(name))
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

then you can write this:

```
a = A()
x = 5
a.x = x
a.x = 10  # raises error
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong comment about adding undefined attributes to an object automatically even without having defined `__setattr__(...)` in the class which would allow it. I really confused it with JavaScript. Fixed the text... it should be correct now.